# Java: Date Format

Tags: java, parsing, date

I am trying to parse the following string to date

2013-02-01T09:37:20EST

I need to compare it with current date to see it is before or after current date.

Here is what I am doing

```
Date formatTime(String time) throws exception
 {
 String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z";
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
 Date expTime = dateFormat.parse(time);
 return expTime;
 }
```

I am getting java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-02-01T09:37:20EST" (at offset 10)

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it seem odd that your input string has a literal "T" and no spaces while your format string has no literal "T" and spaces?

Comment: Yes. It does seems odd and that why I am reaching out to the developer community to help me understand what it means and what should I do about it.

Comment: Thanks to those who have actually answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice the `space` before the `timezone` z and wrap `T` around quotes 'T'

```
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input time `String` does not match your `DateFormat` pattern. You could use:

```
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz";
```

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

The format should be like this: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`